# mongodb Single Point of Failure

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am aware that mongodb has a master-slave architecture.

Therefore, I was thinking that the master would be the single point of failure in mongoDB since it takes care of all the requests and sends it to the slave nodes. However, when the master fails, then a new master is reelected from the slaves. Therefore I need some clarification on where the single point of failure lies.

Does mongoDB have a single point of failure? Is it in the master node?

Thanks,

Comment: Please ask questions which are about administration of MongoDB on https://dba.stackexchange.com. I nominated your question for migration.

Comment: there is no such thing as 'master' anymore, there is a replica set with one primay and many secondaries, when a primary goes down a new one  fom the secondaries takes over as primary. So there is no a single point of failure. Read more here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/

Comment: @nickmilon Not quite correct. Have a look here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/master-slave/

Comment: This documentation remains to support legacy deployments and for archival purposes only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB can be set up in a way that there is no single point of failure (at least none specific to MongoDB).

When you set up replication as suggested (which includes primary, secondary and an arbiter on a 3rd server), the secondary will take the role of the primary when it goes down. Keep in mind that this only works when the applications know both the primary and the secondary (how to make it aware depends on the driver).

When you have a sharded cluster, the mongo router process (`mongos`) and the config servers becomes additional possible points of failure, but you can also set up reduntant routers and config servers. To send the clients to another mongos server when theirs goes down, you need a 3rd party load-balancing solution.

For [a proper production MongoDB setup with clustering](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/), MongoDB Inc. suggests:

- At least 2 mongos routers
- Exactly 3 config servers
- 3 servers per shard (primary, secondary and arbiter), where the arbiters do not necessarily need dedicated servers and can share hardware with the routers, config servers, members of a **different** replica-set or app servers.